# GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl Returns a folder from another web (CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I have a simple web structure:

Site collection: `var siteUrl = "http://hub-site/sites/home"`

Sub Site       : `var folderUrl = "http://hub-site/sites/home/subhome1"`

In `subhome1` i have a document library with a folder named 'TEST'

```
http://hub-site/sites/home/subhome1/Documents/Test
```

Running this code on a site collection web returns true for a folder that only exists on the subsite. How this makes sense?

```
using(ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl)) {
    try {
        Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
        ctx.Load(folder, f => f.Files.Include(c => c.Name, c => c.ServerRelativeUrl), f => f.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.Folders);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    } catch (Exception) {
      //this call never fails
    }
}
```

Even if i try `folderUrl` as a relative url as `/sites/home/subhome1/Documents/Test` it still works.

Obviously it return a wrong 'Document' folder from the wrong web. What am i missing?

Comment: Try changing the client context to use sub site url instead of site collection url.

Comment: It is beyond the point. Why do I get the folder on wrong web. Why is not throwing folder/file is not found?

Comment: Check the value what was retuning GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl

Comment: Ok, i check the value. It is a "Folder" and it is not null. But it the wrong one. From the wrong web. My question still stands.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58828)